# linq - order by who has been selected

Tags: c#, linq

I am wondering how I could `orderby` who has been selected in a list in `linq`.

For example, I have 4 names in a list

1. Bob
2. Sue
3. Ryan
4. Sarah

Just say the numbers beside them are their associated ID.

So a user selects "Sue and Sarah" - I want Sue and Sarah to be now on top of the list

2 - Sue
 4 - Sarah
 1 - Bob
 3 - Ryan

The Linq I have is

```
List<entity> = List.OrderBy(x => x.id == IDsSelected).GroupBy() // Probably not group by...
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `OrderBy` with a `bool` but you have to use `OrderByDescending` if the `true`s should be on top of the list( i remember that by treating `true` as `1` and `false` as `0`):

```
List<entity> = List
    .OrderByDescending(x => IDsSelected.Contains(x.Id))
    .ThenBy(x => x.Name)  // if desired
    .ToList();
```